# Optimal way to store in MySQL available years for a parts DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm storing car parts in a database. Obviously, some parts will only fit on certain years of a certain vehicle.

When inputting the parts to MySQL, I'm having the user just use this format for the dates, "41, 42, 43, 45, 46" etc.. I then just implode, explode in PHP. That works, for what I needed to do.

Now I need to pull parts based on the years they are available. I don't want to have to use a multiple select box in my form if I can help it.

Any ideas?

Comment: An example would be a major help.

Comment: Is your question how to store it in a database or how to display it on the web site?

Comment: The question is how to store it. I think I found the answer below. It was more of a logic question that a "programming" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Never, ever store more than one information in a single field, if you want to access them separately. Never.**

You will need to rework you DB to have a jointable between model years and parts instead of haveing all model years crammed into a single field of your parts table.

Some tricky textual select will sort of work, but it will definitly kill your performance. If this is about a full parts catalog even for a single model, it will kill your performance to the point of unusability.

Sorry: Better honest than polite, if you really can't have both.

Comment: I came here for honest answers so thank you. I meant to come back yesterday but got caught up with some things. I was actually worried about performance issues, creating a loop for each row that is pulled out seems extreme. I like the example below, I may try something like that.

Comment: @Dan The example below does exactly what I mean: my "jointable" is exactly what Stephen is suggesting - a table to join the parts with the years. This was never ment to be resolved in a loop, but in a join (hence the name jointable).

Comment: I understand :) You're explaining the logic, he's showing some basic syntax. I understand all the syntax it's the logic that was confusing me. Even though it's basic stuff, I guess it was late. Thanks to you both :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a many-to-many relationship...So create another table

Example...

```
part_id | Year
--------------
  1      1995
  1      1996
  2      1995
  2      1997
  3      1998
```

etc etc...

Then you can get all the years a part works with using something like

```
select *
from parts
join parts_years
    on (part_id = parts.id);
```

Comment: I'm going to try this today, for some reason I just couldn't get my brain to think of the right way to do this. Thanks for the help!